# Define non rectangular geometry and generate a mesh python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to simulate seepage through a dam wall so I need to input the geometry of the dam and generate a mesh. Below is the shape of the geometry I want to mesh :
[image: Here]

It is easy to generate a gridmesh for a rectangular shape but I am struggling with this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use a mesh grid here?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding, the problem is how do i make a mesh grid using the outline of the shape as a boundary. i am new to this so i dont know if there is a better way to do this

Comment: What kinds of calculations are you going to do with this mesh.  By itself `numpy` isn't a very good tool for defining irregular meshes/grids.  About the best you can do is create the rectangular mesh, and then map the values on to your shape (i.e. stretch the vertical positions).

Comment: The way i am calculating the seepage is by using the finite deference method of solving for the laplace equation

Comment: how can i map the values into the shape, can you direct me to a resource please